# Numerical Optimization methods?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

What kind of functions are suitable for numerical optimization methods such as Newton, Gradient Descent, ... ?
Any conditions?

Comment: What kind of optimimization problem? Discrete, convex, quadratic, constrained,...?

Comment: it is quadratic with positive constraint.

Answer (score 1):

There are different algorithms for different classes of functions. Hundreds of them. Generally speaking, optimization gets more difficult if the objective function is non-convex or derivatives can not be computed (for example). Not impossible; just more difficult.

If you're looking for an optimization algorithm to handle a specific class of functions then [this guide](http://www.neos-guide.org/Optimization-Guide) might be a good place to start.